# Why does Android download pause, and only continue after restart?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, downloading

Sometimes when I download apps (from the market), the download gets paused. After the download gets paused, I am unable to continue the download. But after the restart my device and then retry downloading, it works fine. 
What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: are you rooted?

Comment: @jlehenbauer, yes

Comment: I see that sometimes. What happens if you long-press the download progress entry and choose "Cancel"?

Comment: Closely related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/unable-to-download-applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens generally when Kernel discards Market from memory. In Android, there're many ways to achieve multi-tasking. Market app achieves it by running its service in background. This way Market app isn't killed. But, when kernel runs out of memory, it has no other choices. It kills other apps (even having running service) to reclaim memory, otherwise device would be crashed. Such power killing returns unstable & unexpected results.

So, to prevent it lower down running app load from system. You can hunt down running apps from *Settings* ~> *Applications* ~> *Running Services*. Simply uninstall all unwanted always-running apps.

Plus, Market might have memory leaks etc. type bugs on your device. So, its better to contact Android support if previous step doesn't help. They really respond (don't think its Google).

Comment: Perfect answer. Never occurred to me that there app could get killed. Nice

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on your device and your version of Android. 
As a temporary remedy you could try and force a stop of the market application instead of having to reboot your device manually every time.

Pressing menu - settings - applications - manage applications - all - market - force stop should close the market and restart the download when you retry.

Comment: I have a solution... `reboot the device` , but  that's not my question at all

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem. They start, they pause, they quit, and you have to try again. The solution for me, albeit a little overboard, was to flash a new ROM. This was not the only reason, and i noticed this download issue only happened after my device got pretty bogged down (not much internal storage left), but regardless of the reasons, reflashing took care of the problem.

i know erasing your phone is obvious and not optimal, but a fresh start is always good :)

Comment: come on... that is not an answer. :)

Comment: haha i know it's not a fun one, but it completely solved the issue for me :) i think it has something to do with storage space and the fact that the phone is rooted; the market was made to work with standard versions of android, so modded ones can get messy sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, just go to the download manager from settings-apps and turn of notification and again turn on notification that's all, it work or me.